# C# - How do you get the nameof a property of a composite object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a Company class that has a composite object as a property that has company object as its property and so on for many levels. I need to get the name of the property at the deepest level with the least amount of code.

Here's a pseudocode for the case:

```
class Company
{
    public Person Boss
    {
        public Document CV
        {
             public string Title;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get a string result of ***"Company.Boss.CV.Title"*** with as less code as possible. The naive way of doing this would be to try `nameof(Company.Boss.CV.Title)` but as we know this will result in just "Title".

I need to work with types not pure strings to allow the compiler to throw an error whenever someone changes the property names.
Obviously something like:

```
string.Join('.', nameof(Company), nameof(Company.Boss), nameof(Company.Boss.CV), nameof(Company.Boss.CV.Title))
```

will work correctly 100% of the time but there is too much boilerplate code. Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: A MemberExpression? `GetMemberName<Company>(c => c.Boss.CV.Title)`, where you use reflection to get the relevant names? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression

Comment: @CodeCaster that and some string manipulation did the trick! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an Expression and decompose it, something like:

```
Expression<Func<Company, object>> myExpr = (c) => c.Boss.CV.Title;

var expr = myExpr.Body;
var sb = new StringBuilder();

// Traverse the expression
while (expr != null)
{
    switch (expr.NodeType){
        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
            var memberExpr = ((MemberExpression)expr);
            sb.Insert(0, "." + memberExpr.Member.Name, 1);
            expr = memberExpr.Expression;
            break;
        case ExpressionType.Parameter:
            var paramExpr = ((ParameterExpression)expr);
            parts.Add(paramExpr.Type.Name);
            sb.Insert(0, paramExpr.Type.Name, 1);
            expr = null;
            break;
        default:
            expr = null;
            break;
    }
}

var propertyPath = sb.ToString(); // "Company.Boss.CV.Title"
```

**Using ExpressionVisitor**

Implementing a custom ExpressionVisitor can help with clarity of the code.

```
public class MyExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor{
    private List<string> parts;

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        parts.Add(node.Member.Name);
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        parts.Add(node.Type.Name);
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }

    public string GetPath(Expression e)
    {
        parts = new List<string>();
        Visit(e is LambdaExpression ? ((LambdaExpression)e).Body : e);
        parts.Reverse();
        return string.Join(".", parts);
    }
}
```

You can then call it using

```
Expression<Func<Company, object>> myExpr = (c) => c.Boss.CV.Title;
var myVisitor = new MyExpressionVisitor();
var propertyPath = myVisitor.GetPath(myExpr);
```

Comment: That is basically what got the job done. Thank you!